# Input form not submitting after getJSON call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, getjson

I have been trying to create a submit form that both makes getJSON call to display the response on html template and submits input. But I can only either submit the input or display response received from getJSON call. I have tried removing preventDefault method and adding it to my function but it is still not working.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions!

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="newpost" style="width:300px;" placeholder="post here...">
        {% if user %}
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ user.key.id() }}">
            <input id="inputButton" type="submit" value="Done">
            <div id="jsonInfo"></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function (){

                                $('#inputButton').click(function (e) {
                                    var URL = 'URLEXAMPLE';
                                    $.getJSON(URL, function(data){

                                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                                        var info = data[i].content;
                                        $("#jsonInfo").append(info);
                                    };
                                });
                            e.preventDefault();


                        });


                });

            </script>
        {% else %}
            <input type="button" class="button_active" onclick="location.href='/login'" value="Done">
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

After the for do a

`$('#form').submit();` to submit the form, `e.preventDefault();` is currently blocking the default form submission so you can send the ajax request

Comment: form is submitted but the AJAX response disappears immediatly

Comment: this is the normal behavior your are redirecting from the page man

Comment: is there a way to submit input then get AJAX response by one click?

Comment: the simple answer is yes but you don't need ajax for that

Comment: Great! would you mind explaining how? I am working on a project and it requires me to make an AJAX call and submit input at the same time by clicking one button. If it's too much trouble, I completely understand. thank you for your help.

Comment: you do a simple form submit, you get the date from the ajax call using curl or any other server side pulling function